What permission is required when saving an image to photo library using Flutter?
I'm using image_gallery_saver and permission_handler to save images to iOS photo library. I have the following defined in info.plist. When I try to save the image, I get prompted twice, one for each entry.  If I explicitly request for read permission, then I don't get the prompt for the first entry. However, that's misleading since I need to ask for write permission to the photo library. If I deny the first prompt, I don't see second prompt but it has no impact on Permission.photos.status I wonder what it should be the correct way to ask permission to write to photo library for iOS. It seems that Android doesn't require permission to write to photo library.
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>

